# Extracting application Resource

Tags: c#, wpf, resources

I want to add a text file from my applications's Resources to my Desktop.
Can someone explain me how to do this? Should i set my file in my application as Resource or Content?

Answer (score 0):

Right click your **Properties** in the **Solution Explorer**,click **Open**, open **Resouces** tab,right click to your file and select Export to file..

here is some explanation about it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k989cfy(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: It does not tell me how to extract it?

Comment: sorry  i didn't see that,try right click to your file you must see Export to file.. property

Comment: Sorry but the option is not there. I want to extract my resource programmatically

Comment: can you access your file using "Resources.filename" ? if you can access it than you can use filestream to save it,don't you know how to use filestream?